# Values turn to Nan when indexing the keys in a dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

i am trying to become a self taught data analyst.
In Pandas when i index different names in the second part of the code, the values turn from 450 to Nan, from 500 to Nan and 380 becomes 380.0 (float).
Also, the dtype turns from int64 to float64.
Any ideas why this happens?
Also if i copy an example from w3schools is it displayed fine.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


calories= {"Day 1": 450, "Day 2": 500, "day 3": 380}
new_series= pd.Series(calories)
print(new_series)

**#Second part of code**
new_series_1= pd.Series(calories, index=["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"])
print(new_series_1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code.  It is a simple fix.  Python, like a lot of programs, is case sensitive.  You just need to revise your statement.

Change from:

```
new_series_1= pd.Series(calories, index=["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"])
```

to:

```
new_series_1= pd.Series(calories, index=["Day 1", "Day 2", "day 3"])
```

Note the capital letters.

When I made sure that the column names matched, I got similar output.

```
Day 1    450
Day 2    500
day 3    380
dtype: int64
Day 1    450
Day 2    500
day 3    380
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is my first interaction with stackoverflow and guys i really aprecciate the help!! 
Thank you a lot, i made it clear in my mind now!!

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

In `new_series_1`, `calories` keys don't match with the `index` values, and the Series is being reindexed with the latter, hence the `NaN` and `float64`.

### Explanation

First you initialize `new_series` with `calories`, which is a `dict` with `int` values:

```
calories= {"Day 1": 450, "Day 2": 500, "day 3": 380}
new_series= pd.Series(calories)
```

So Pandas knows they can be treated best as `int64`.

Then you set 2 different values in index, `day 1` and `day 2`, no capitalized:

```
new_series_1= pd.Series(calories, index=["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"])
```

There was no more correspondence between `calories`'s keys and `index` values, so Pandas defaulted to `float64` for a best guess.
In fact, an example in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) shows that:

> Constructing Series from a dictionary with an Index specified

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ser
a   1
b   2
c   3
dtype: int64
```

> The keys of the dictionary match with the Index values, hence the Index values have no effect.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
ser
x   NaN
y   NaN
z   NaN
dtype: float64
```

> Note that the Index is first build with the keys from the dictionary.
> **After this the Series is reindexed with the given Index values, hence
> we get all NaN as a result**.

And [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html#pandas-index) it explains when it changes `dtype`, based on `Index`:

> **If dtype is None, we find the dtype that best fits the data.** If an
> actual dtype is provided, we coerce to that dtype if it’s safe.
> Otherwise, an error will be raised.

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend. I appreciate the help and also your time!! 
You made me fully understand it and make it clear in my mind!!